# Tango with Django Chapter 6 - URL won't work

Tags: python, django

I have been going through "Tango with Django" and have been unable to solve this problem myself or by looking online. Would anyone know how to approach it?

The relevant page should be opened when I click on the link, but none are going through, which makes me assume something in my view.py file is wrong or even in my url.py or model.py file (index.html seems to be working correctly).

Views.py

```
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from Spaces.models import Category, Page

def index(request):
    # Query the databse for a list of ALL categories currently stored.
    # Order the categories by no likes in descending order .
    # Retrieve the top 5 only - or all if less than 5.
    # Place the list in context_dict dictionary
    # that will be passed to the template engine.
    category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]

    context_dict = {'categories': category_list}

    # Render the response and send it back!

    return render(request, 'Spaces/index.html', context=context_dict)


def about(request):
    context_dict = {'boldmessage':"Crunchy, creamy, cookie, candy, cupcake!"}
    return render(request, 'Spaces/about.html', context=context_dict)

def show_category(request, category_name_slug):
    # Create a context dictionary which we can pass
    # to the template rendering engine.
    context_dict = {}
    try:
        # Can we find a category name slug with the given name?
        # If we can't, the .get() method raises a DoesNotExist exception.
        # So the .get() method returns one model instance or raises an exception.
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
        # Retrieve all of the associated pages.
        # Note that filter() will return a list of page objects or an empty list
        pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)
        # Adds our results list to the template context under name pages.
        context_dict['pages'] = pages
        # We also add the category object from
        # the database to the context dictionary.
        # We'll use this in the template to verify that the category exists.
        context_dict['category'] = category
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        # We get here if we didn't find the specified category.
        # Don't do anything -
        # the template will display the "no category" message for us.
        context_dict['category'] = None
        context_dict['pages'] = None
        # Go render the response and return it to the client.
        return render(request, 'Spaces/category.html', context_dict)
```

Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from Spaces import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$',
        views.show_category, name='show_category'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self): # For Python 2, use __unicode__ too
        return self.title
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
  <title>Spaces</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Spaces says...</h1>
  <div>hey there partner!</div>

  <div>
    {% if categories %}
    <ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'show_category' category_name_slug=category.slug %}">{{ category.name }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
    <strong>There are no categories present.</strong>
    {% endif %}
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="/Spaces/about/">About Space</a><br />
    <img src="{% static 'images/Spaces.jpg' %}" alt="Picture of Rango" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

populate_spaces.py (test script)

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE',
                        'Space.settings')
import django
django.setup()
from Spaces.models import Category, Page

def populate():
    #First, we will create lists of dictionaries containing the pages
    # we want to add into each category.
    # Then we will create a dictionary of dictionaries for our categories.
    # This might seem a little bit confusing, but it allows us to iterate
    # through each data structure, and add the data to our models.

    python_pages = [
    {"title": "Prahran",
    "url":"http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/", "views":20},
    {"title": "South Yarra",
    "url":"http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/", "views":25},
    {"title": "etcetera",
    "url":"http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/", "views":35}
    ]

    django_pages = [
    {"title" :  "Official Django Tutorial",
    "url" :"https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/", "views":36},
    {"title":"Django Rocks",
    "url":"http://www.djangorocks.com/", "views":23},
    {"title":"How to Tango with Django",
    "url":"http://www.tangowithdjango.com/", "views":45}
    ]

    other_pages = [
    {"title":"Bottle",
    "url":"http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/", "views":3},
    {"title":"Flask",
    "url":"http://flask.pocoo.org",
    "views":34}]

    cats = {"Python": {"pages": python_pages, "views": 128, "likes":64},
            "Django": {"pages": django_pages, "views": 64, "likes":32},
            "Other Frameworks": {"pages": other_pages, "views": 32, "likes":16} }

    # If you want to add more categories or pages,
    # Add them to the dictionaries above.

    # The code below goes through the cats dictionary, then adds each category
    # and then adds all the associated pages for that category.





    for cat, cat_data in cats.items():
        c = add_cat(cat,cat_data)
        for p in cat_data["pages"]:
            add_page(c, p["title"], p["url"], p["views"])

    #Print out the categories we have added.
    for c in Category.objects.all():
        for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
            print("-{0})-{1}".format(str(c), str(p)))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title)[0]
    p.url=url
    p.views=views
    p.save()
    return p

def add_cat(name, cat_data):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    c.likes = cat_data["likes"]
    c.views = cat_data["views"]
    c.save()
    return c

    # Start execution here!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Starting Spaces population script...")
    populate()
```

Comment: make sure debug is True in settings and tell the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Debug is actually been set to True. There is no error as such - the code just defaults to sending to URL none.

Comment: It leads to url being "spaces/category/none

Comment: your categories don't have any slug, check your database. When creating categories make sure you add slug

Comment: Category class has slugs!

Comment: Of course the class has slug, but does its objects have slug? or is it defaulting to NULL

Comment: Oh you're correct! How do I correct this!!!

Comment: Show the code which is creating categories. or use id instead of slug, all categories has id but then your urls will look like `127.0.0.1/spaces/category/5` and user will then try the url `127.0.0.1/spaces/category/6` and so on which is something you might not want.

Comment: I updated the test script that populates the dbase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.

Essentially I had indented a return function in my view.py file incorrectly!